# How Do I Import 75+ Groups

Tags: import, groups

What's the best way to batch import a list of groups? The list contains 75+ entries, so having a team member manually enter each group is not the best use of time.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

CiviCRM by default does not have an option to import groups. However, there is a third-party extension that provides a user interface to import anything through the more powerful CiviCRM API.

First, install the API CSV GUI extension:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui

Then click the new menu item that appears and select Entity to Import: Group.

Version 1.1 includes the wrong alias path, so remember to type "civicrm/" before "csvimporter/import" or else a Page Not Found error will be thrown.

```
mywebsite.com/csvimporter/import
```

should really be...

```
mywebsite.com/civicrm/csvimporter/import
```

Alternatively, install from git: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport