# Restoring groups and linked contacts

Tags: groups, import

50 groups were deleted by mistake. Please don't ask how.

So from a 2 weeks old backup, we're able to extract a CSV from civicrm_group and civicrm_group_contact

group_id, name, contact_id, email

We would like to reimport the groups and their assignation to contacts. The contacts are already in the system normally. We would not want duplicate users

Afraid of simply going to the civicrm_group_contact table and just filling it through phpmyadmin

Any tip? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident the users are all there, you could do an import with the CSV dump you mentioned, using the **Group ID** and **Contact ID**.

1) [Batch import the groups](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-do-i-import-75-groups) using the [API csv Import](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui) module.

2) Assuming the Group IDs could be imported and match up, you could import the users via their internal IDs. Instead of selecting "Group" for the *Entity To Import* (as in step 1), you can import "GroupContact" and match up the Group ID field and the Contact ID field.

Comment: Thanks Laryn! Looks promising... I am trying to install it according to this page https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Extensions , but I am missing the following menu item : Administer » System Settings » Manage CiviCRM Extensions

Comment: Ok! I was able to hack my way through. But now the API csv Import module does not have a field called "Entity To Import... looks like I can only import contacts.

Comment: Update. We're at 4.2 The API CSV Import only seem to be working for groups on 4.6 ... Any other solution? thanks!